# What does it mean if chkdsk runs for several days?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, crash, task-manager, chkdsk

I ran into a problem where my Windows 8 computer all of a sudden ran really slowly. After opening up Task Manager, I noticed that 50% Disk Activity was being used, even though the total of all the apps running were about 0.5 MB/s in Disk Activity. So, I restarted the computer, and since then, I haven't been able to boot into Windows.

So, I ran `chkdsk` from the Windows 8 DVD, and it's been running for 20 hours so far. It's currently on Stage 4 of 5, on file 182,000 of 251,000 (approximately). When it's stopped moving, I assume it's trying to fix a file, because there are notices indicating that Windows has replaced a bad cluster.

It hasn't technically been running for a day yet, but I assume it will be; I'll be leaving it to run overnight (for the second time) and I assume it will still be running. Assuming it does continue to run by then, should I just let it finish? How long should I let it run for at most? And let's say it actually manages to fix everything, then is everything all good, even if it has ran for an abnormally long amount of time?

I'm obviously hoping that the problems are just on the surface, and are not hardware-related (i.e. a dead hard drive). This Windows 8 computer (and the hard drive) is only about two months old, so I would be saddened if the thing is already dead.

Comment: something is clearly wrong with your hard drive or your windows 8. leaning toward your hard drive tho

Comment: This type of behavior indicates the hard drive has failed or is on it very last leg.  I hope you have a backup of your files

Comment: let it run and run until you stop it. I let one go for days and it never seemed to move....... then I stopped it. And then it ran fine and I recovered the files as fast as I could. Then threw it away. If you get that win8 hdd to boot, dont wait a min, recover the files... it might never boot again.

Comment: Okay thanks. What's the best way to get files off of it? Do I need to get a HD enclosure to make it into an external drive, or should I get another external drive then connect it to this computer to copy things off? Ideally I'd like to clone the whole thing rather than copy one file at a time. Or would you advise against that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my hard drive had a lot of bad sectors on it. So, I used [HDD Regenerator](http://www.dposoft.net/) to recover my bad sectors, then used [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/trueimage/) to clone my internal drive to an external one before I lost it for good.